# What's the meaning or synonym of "as a matter of convenience"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What's the meaning or synonym of "as a matter of convenience" in below sentence?

> *In the computerized system that most companies have today, accounts are maintained on magnetic tapes or disks.
>
>   However, **as a matter of convenience**, accountants still refer to the all-inclusive group of company accounts as the general ledger, or simply the ledger.*

Comment: "However, as a matter of convenience, accountants." is not a grammatical sentence in my opinion.

Comment: You can say *for convenience reasons*.

Comment: There should be no fullstop/period after *accountants*. The phrase should carry straight on to read: *accountants still refer.....*. In this context a matter of convenience means an easy way or short cut, which everybody understands, to refer to something else, presumably something with a long name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before computers, accounting records were kept by hand in a book, called a "ledger".  The quote talks about how that is all done on a computer now.  There is no longer an actual ledger and yet accountants still use the archaic term.  It might seem logical to update the terminology so that it is consistent with modern practices, but they don't.  Why is that?  The phrase in question, "as a matter of convenience", addresses the reason.

"As a matter of convenience" means that there is not some compelling or important technical consideration.  They do it just because it is easier to keep doing it that way.  It's simpler, it saves having to change anything.

"Convenience" in this usage refers to the ability to proceed without difficulty, to do something in an easy or effortless way.  See [definition here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/convenience).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and attention, I appreciate you so much.